# How to display all values from DB to Android via JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, database

I wanna make an app which gets some data via json from a MySQL database and display them on the app. I have made it to show only one result, but I want them all to be displayed. I should add a loop somewhere? Could you please help? Thank you!

**PlacesActivity.java**

```
public class PlacesActivity extends Activity {
TextView place_id1;
TextView user_id1;
TextView name1;
TextView description1;
TextView type1;
TextView coordinates1;
Button Btngetdata;

private static String url = "theurlishere";

private static final String TAG_PLACES = "places";
private static final String TAG_PLACEID = "place_id";
private static final String TAG_USERID = "user_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG_COORDINATES = "coordinates";

JSONArray places = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute();

        }
    });

}

 private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        place_id1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.place_id);
        user_id1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_id);
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        description1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
        type1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.type);
        coordinates1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinates);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlacesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            allplaces = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALLPLACES);
            JSONObject c = allplaces.getJSONObject(0);

            String places_id = c.getString(TAG_PLACEID);
            String user_id = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
            String coordinates = c.getString(TAG_COORDINATES);

            place_id1.setText(places_id);
            user_id1.setText(user_id);
            name1.setText(name);
            description1.setText(description);
            type1.setText(type);
            coordinates1.setText(coordinates);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}}
```

**activity_places.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.media1.thesistest2.PlacesActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user_id"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place_id"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_id"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coordinates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/type"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/getdata"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:text="Get Data" />
```

Comment: Try looking for examples with listviews and arrayadapters

Comment: You need a ListView to present all the data. In the line where you get the JSONArray you must do a loop getting all the data, and passing it to a Custom Adapter in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the answer to this, this example is exactly what I was looking for: https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

Thank you :)